# Gattling stress tool to parse json out of JSP

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a spring service which renders JSP page. Spring controller sets JSON data in a request attribute, which i use in my JSP. Can anyone tell how can i parse this JSON data. I know if my web service response was a plain json , i can parse using jsonPath. But in my case JSON is a part of JSP. So I am kinda stuck.

Comment: Do you have control over the Spring controller? If so perhaps consider updating it so that it's not putting a JSON string in the request attribute. Parse the JSON in the controller, and then pass a Java Bean representation to the view instead.

Answer (score 0):

You mean that your JSON is inside your HTML, probably in a Javascript variable?
And I guess using a regex to retrieve the elements your interested in is not enough and that you really want the JSON string?

If so, you can first use a regex check in order to extract your JSON content from your HTML. Beware that if your JSON string is on several lines, you might have to enable some regex features such as [multiline or dotall](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). See

Then, you can transform your regex output into a JSON tree, using the [check transform](https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Checks#wiki-transforming) step. There, you can parse the JSON string with the engine of your choice. Gatling ships with [json-smart](https://code.google.com/p/json-smart/).

Another solution is to build your own check. The procedure for Gatling 2 has been described in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/EUvmheD8rkA) on Gatling's Google Group.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion. I am right now using this linkgroups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gatling/xi05ziICHSY/buvvQKXZ_pgJ. It explains to extract JSON out of body. 

.check(bodyString.transform(x => x.map(y => {
    val json = y.asJson.convertTo[Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, Boolean]]]]
    json("data").filter(_._2("foo")).keySet
  })).whatever.saveAs("foos")))

Can you tell me if its right approach and what packages i should import in order to use jsonsmart parsers.

Comment: import net.minidev.json.JSONValue._